# Baking JavaScript Files in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-bake

I was wondering if it is possible to Bake JS Files in CakePHP? I have written some custom cake bake templates that fit our layout and standards, and take care of the crud involved in our controllers and views. I'd like to take it one step further by baking some methods found in most of our javascript classes such as index, view, add, and save.

Is it possible to do so and output into app/webroot/js?

One workaround that comes to mine is just having the js output directly into the index file and then moving it into its own respective file, but I'd like an automagic solution instead.

Thoughts on this?

Comment: of course you can do that in your bake scripts. they are just plain simple PHP after all. But why asking us that? We sure won't do the job for you :)

Comment: I don't think you understand the question very well Mark. Try re-reading it. I wasn't asking anyone to do my work :-) Moreso I was asking how to put baked javascript files in app/webroot/js.